# Methods don't work subscribeOn(), observeOn(), subscribe() by Kotlin

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, kotlin, observable

[Here is my code, I tried everything that is generally possible, but did not get rid of the errors. I did everything by example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI5vQ.png)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Yawa3jmkiw Please help with this problem

[Implemented Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uEBo.png)